# How to read a string starting from specific index?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm currently making a MFC program written in C++. What I want to do is that I want to make a function to read a string from specific index. Here is the code I'm working on:

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::formatting(int start, int end, char *content, BinTreeNode *node){
    char *temp1 = "", *temp2 = "", *temp3 = "";
    int var1, var2;

    sscanf(&(content[start]), "%s %s %s", temp1, temp2, temp3);
    if (strcmp(temp1, "minus") == 0 || strcmp(temp1, "if") == 0){
        if (strcmp(temp1, "minus") == 0){
            node->isMinus = TRUE;
            var1 = atoi(temp2);
            var2 = atoi(temp3);
            node->operand1 = var1;
            node->operand2 = var2;
        }
        else if (strcmp(temp1, "if") == 0)
        {
            node->isIf = TRUE;
            var1 = atoi(temp2);
            var2 = atoi(temp3);
            node->operand1 = var1;
            node->operand2 = var2;
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp(temp3, "minus") == 0 || strcmp(temp3, "if") == 0){
        if (strcmp(temp3, "minus") == 0){
            node->isMinus = TRUE;
            var1 = atoi(temp1);
            var2 = atoi(temp2);
            node->operand1 = var1;
            node->operand2 = var2;
        }
        else if (strcmp(temp3, "if") == 0)
        {
            node->isIf = TRUE;
            var1 = atoi(temp1);
            var2 = atoi(temp2);
            node->operand1 = var1;
            node->operand2 = var2;
        }
    }
    else{
        MessageBox(_T("Invalid Format"), _T("Error"), MB_OK);
    }

}
```

The thing is that it occurs some errors regaring pointer. I don't know why the code makes that kind of problem and need some help. Please would you be my savior?

Comment: If you are working in c++, you should use [std::string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) objects rather than char* variables. It will allow you a lot of simpler tricks, like operators == or != rather than strcmp. And you will have your solution with `substr` member function.

Comment: What are you trying to parse? Why don't you use std::string or MFC CString for parsing? Your code is basically plain C.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But here is another problem. What if I don't know the size of the string that will gonna read from a string? In that case, isn't sscanf method is more reliable than substr method in cstring?

Comment: Andrew, the string I want to parse is a code written in LISP style like this.

Comment: ((1 2 MINUS)(3 4 IF) MINUS)

Comment: I don't know well the MFC, so i don't know if there is any sscanf implementation... But really, look at the std::string documentation. It will calculate sizes and reallocate if necessary without your intervention, while your actual sscanf use non-allocated pointers, so segmentation fault potential is high...

Comment: Please provide an example of LISP style snippet you are trying to parse. And please don't use C style strings (char*) in C++ until there is no other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this implementation: http://howtowriteaprogram.blogspot.ru/2010/11/lisp-interpreter-in-90-lines-of-c.html

A language interpreter has two parts:

1. **Parsing**: The parsing component takes an input program in the form of
   a sequence of characters, verifies it according to the syntactic
   rules of the language, and translates the program into an internal
   representation. In a simple interpreter the internal representation
   is a tree structure (often called an abstract syntax tree) that
   closely mirrors the nested structure of statements or expressions in
   the program. In a language translator called a compiler there is
   often a series of internal representations, starting with an
   abstract syntax tree, and progressing to a sequence of instructions
   that can be directly executed by the computer. Refer to *read()*, *read_from()* and *tokenize()* functions in provided implementation.
2. **Execution**: The internal representation is then processed according
   to the semantic rules of the language, thereby carrying out the
   computation. The execution function is called *eval()*.

Comment: Wow, that code is quite complicated. I should take time and look at the code.

Comment: It is actually pretty simple. The main idea is that you need 2 things for your interpreter: lexical analyzer (tokenizer) and the expression evaluator.

Comment: Rather than posting a link, it would have been more helpful if you posted a brief description of what the link explains.  What happens in the future if the link is no longer valid?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback on that. I've added short explanation.